# I can't copy the png image

Tags: c, png, libpng

I tried to implement the function of copying the specified area of the png image, but the "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" crashes. Checked to go beyond the bounds of the array, just paint over the selected pixels, everything worked. The coordinates of two points are fed to the input of the function, along which the desired area is constructed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <png.h>

#define FILE_NAME "spongebob.png"

struct png{

    int width, height;
    png_byte color_type;
    png_byte bit_depth;

    png_structp png_ptr;
    png_infop info_ptr;
    int number_of_passes;
    png_bytep *row_pointers;
};

void openPNG(struct png* image, char* fileName)
{

    int x,y;
    char heder[8];

    FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "rb");

    if(!fp) printf("file is not opend\n");

    fread(heder, 1, 8, fp);

    image->png_ptr = png_create_read_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    image->info_ptr = png_create_info_struct(image->png_ptr);


   png_init_io(image->png_ptr, fp);

   png_set_sig_bytes(image->png_ptr, 8);

    png_read_info(image->png_ptr, image->info_ptr);

    image->width = png_get_image_width(image->png_ptr, image->info_ptr);
    image->height = png_get_image_height(image->png_ptr, image->info_ptr);
    image->color_type = png_get_color_type(image->png_ptr, image->info_ptr);
    image->bit_depth = png_get_bit_depth(image->png_ptr, image->info_ptr);

    image->row_pointers = (png_bytep *) malloc(sizeof(png_bytep) * image->height);


    for (y = 0; y < image->height; y++)
        image->row_pointers[y] = (png_byte *) malloc(png_get_rowbytes(image->png_ptr, image->info_ptr));

    png_read_image(image->png_ptr, image->row_pointers);

    fclose(fp);
}

void doNewFile(struct png* image, char* fileName)
{

    int x, y;

    FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "wb");

    if(!fp) printf("file is not open {doNewFile}\n");

    image->png_ptr = png_create_write_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL);


    image->info_ptr = png_create_info_struct(image->png_ptr);

    png_init_io(image->png_ptr, fp);

    png_set_IHDR(image->png_ptr, image->info_ptr, image->width, image->height,
                 image->bit_depth, image->color_type, PNG_INTERLACE_NONE,
                 PNG_COMPRESSION_TYPE_BASE, PNG_FILTER_TYPE_BASE);

    png_write_info(image->png_ptr, image->info_ptr);

    png_write_image(image->png_ptr, image->row_pointers);

    png_write_end(image->png_ptr, NULL);

    for (y = 0; y < image->height; y++)
        free(image->row_pointers[y]);
    free(image->row_pointers);

    fclose(fp);

}



void doCopy(struct png *image, int Sx, int Sy, int Fx, int Fy)
{

    int x, y;
    int lenX = Fx - Sx + 1;
    int lenY = Fy - Sy + 1;

    printf("lenX = %d  lenY = %d\n", lenX, lenY);

    png_bytep *new_row_pointers =(png_bytep *) malloc(sizeof(png_bytep) * lenY); 

    for(y = 0; y < lenY; y++){
        new_row_pointers[y] = (png_byte *)malloc(sizeof(png_byte *) * lenX); 

        png_byte *torow = new_row_pointers[y]; 
        png_byte *row = image->row_pointers[Sy + y];

        for (x = 0; x < lenX; x++){


            png_byte *toptr = &(torow[x*4]); 
            png_byte *ptr = &(row[(Sx+x*4)]);


            toptr[0] = ptr[0];
            toptr[1] = ptr[1]; 
            toptr[2] = ptr[2];
            toptr[3] = ptr[3];

            /*ptr[0] = 0;
            ptr[1] = 255;      
            ptr[2] = 255;
            ptr[3] = 255;*/

            /*toptr[0] = 0;
            toptr[1] = 255;      
            toptr[2] = 255;   
            toptr[3] = 255;*/


        }
        image->row_pointers = new_row_pointers;  
        image->width = lenX; 
        image->height = lenY;

    }
}

int main(){

    int Sx = 100;
    int Sy = 100;

    int Fx = 2000;
    int Fy = 1000;


    struct png image;

    openPNG(&image, FILE_NAME);
    doCopy(&image, Sx , Sy, Fx, Fy);
    doNewFile(&image, "newFile.png");

}
```

Comment: Is this C or C++?   Don't tag with both tags please, as they are different languages.   This is likely just a C question.  Anyhow, run it in a debugger and post the backtrace.

Comment: Anyhow, if there's an image to load(it also crashes if there isn't), then it crashes on             `toptr[0] = ptr[0];` with ptr = 0x64 x = 0, y = 1, so that seems bad. At least that's where it crashes for the random .png file I grabbed to run it.

Comment: just use pnmcut, or copy the source

Comment: OT: regarding: `if(!fp) printf("file is not opend\n");`  1) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  2) when the error is from a C library function, should also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  The function: `perror()` is made to do this.  If this kind of error occurs, then exit the program, do not continue the program and try to read from the file

Comment: the first two bytes of a .png file is a file type.  The posted code is using the first two bytes as part of the pixel width/height information,  Which it is NOT

Comment: the width, in pixels, must be rounded up to a multiple of 2 to obtain the actual width of the pixel array

Comment: the code needs to look into the image header to find the actual width of each pixel.  The posted code is assuming 32bits, but in can be: `8bits, 16bits, 24bits, or 32bits